# How to output a SharePoint Solution Package after Visual Studio finished building?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I have a SharePoint Project. When Visual Studio project has finished building, it should generate SharePoint Solution Package(WSP) **automatically**.

How can I achieve this automation, using visual studio ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your `.csproj` file in file editor and add the following line at the end just before project closing tag `</Project>`

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <BuildDependsOn>$(BuildDependsOn);CreatePackage</BuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

It will automatically create the package and save in the location that is mentioned in project properties output path. To check this location, right click your project -> Properties -> `Build` (tab) -> at the end there is `Output Path` which is by default set to `bin\Debug`. You can change this path, if you want.

Comment: Works like a cake.. Thanks much Garima. BTW, Where do you get cmdlets like this ? Any reference URLs.

Comment: I agree quite a good point.

Comment: I did it for a project some time back. Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

After you finish building right click on your project and select `Publish` , it will ask for drive on machine, select `Publish to File System` provide it the `Target location` it will create the WSP at the path

Comment: Thanks for the response @inferno, but I looked for automation. I got the solution from Garima's answer.